# MySql Strange (to me) Performance on where clause

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have one table that stores 2k records.
The schema is :

```
CREATE TABLE `tcms_articles` (
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `User_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Category_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Value` longtext,
  `Keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Description` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Images` longtext NOT NULL,
  `Votes` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `Votes_sum` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '5',
  `Views` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Isvisible` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `Isfrontpage` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Istoparticle` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `Expires_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2099-12-31 00:00:00',
  `Date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `article_users` (`User_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `article_section` (`Category_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Isvisible_index` (`Isvisible`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Istoparticle_index` (`Istoparticle`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Expires_date_index` (`Expires_date`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `isfrontpage` (`Isfrontpage`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Date_index` (`Date`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `tcms_articles_categories` FOREIGN KEY (`Category_id`) REFERENCES `tcms_categories` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `tcms_articles_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`User_id`) REFERENCES `tcms_users` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=80 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When i search the table with this query i  have performance problems

`select value from tcms_articles where  istoparticle=1 and isvisible=1 order by date limit 1;`

it takes about 1.50+ seconds!

But when i search like this :

`select value from tcms_articles where  istoparticle=1 order by date limit 1;`

I don't have any problem, it takes about 0.02sec.

Thank you very mutch.

Comment: Consider putting a composite index on fields `(istoparticle, isvisible)`.

Comment: it is't only istoparticle,isvisible etc.

Comment: See http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm Use `EXPLAIN` on your `SELECT` and see what indexes it uses. I don't think it will use any and is actually table-scanning.

Comment: If I were you, i would try to drop and redo the index. Helped me before.

Comment: I've just added composite index but nothing again:/
@Andrew i have done this but it says that it uses:/

Comment: The problem was that i was having problem with indexes.
The interest thing was that "explain" says that it uses the indexes....weird:/

Comment: Dropping and recreating indexes regenerates the statistics. It's a good idea to regenerate these every so often. See `OPTIMIZE` on page three of my link.

Comment: Is this the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tcms_articles ;` ? I somehow doubt it. Can you post that?

Comment: @ypercube Yes, this is the output. Why?

Comment: MySQL usually outputs backquotes, not single quotes. Never seen this, I didn't even think it's possible.

Comment: I have replaced them to " ' ". But this isn't a problem.

Comment: Why, so you make it difficult for others to copy and test? You also changed the `KEY index_name USING HASH (column)` to `KEY index_name (column) USING HASH` ...

Comment: I'm sorry but i've done this because i have formatting problem posting this question. I will change it.

Comment: Now it's fine, thnx. It's easier for others to test if you have code that can be just copied and pasted (and runs without change). You can also use [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to prepare the tables (and possibly a few rows) so others can test, even without having your DBMS in their machine.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a B-tree (not Hash) compound index on `(Istoparticle, Isvisible, Date)` for this query.

Comment: Thank you but i have done that.
It seems that i had curupted indexes i've dropped them 2-3 times nothing. Then somehow when i redropped indexes again, it magically works.

Comment: Now i've fixed the problem (as i say), and i have not the output of explain.